# Choose a 5km radius - google maps API show people + their addresses

Tags: list, api, maps

So I have a problem, and need help with this.

With Google API, is it possible to create a 5km circle, and list all adresses that is within this circle?

Best regards,
Eric

Haven't solved it yet